# Save pid number on a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running my flask application with nohup command on my linux server. I am trying to save PID number as a variable or save just the PID number on output .

For an example , if i run my flask_application with nohup in below command

```
nohup python /home/app/run_flask.py > /home/temp/run_flask.out 2> /home/temp/run_flask.err &
```

this will successfully run in the backgroup and i check if my pid running is by

```
 ps -ef | grep /home/app/run_flask.py
```

my server will return this

```
farid  108708      1  0 23:50 pts/0    00:00:00 python /home/app/run_flask.py
farid  112265  83174  0 23:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto /home/app/run_flask.py
```

PID which i am trying to capture either as a variable or save it to file is 112265  so that i can include this in my shell script to kill process on certain condition .  How can i achieve this ?

I have tried using this command and i was able to print out 112265  , however i am not sure i cant store this as variable by adding 'test1=ps ef....' and if this is the right approach . command used

```
ps -ef | grep /home/app/run_flask.py | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | tail -1
```

Comment: Have your program write its pid to a file.

Comment: You store a command's output using `x=$(...command)` or `x=\`...command\``. Is that what you're looking for? Additionally, make sure to included `|grep -v grep` after `grep /home/...` that filters out your own grep and leaves you only with your command. Finally, consider using `pgrep` instead. There is lot's of previous content about this on SO. Just search for it (google "grep pid").

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
VAR=$(ps -ef | grep something_u_want | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

Then `VAR` will hold the number.

In your example, 112265 was the PID of your grep process. You should probably exclude it by running a `grep -v grep` afterwards.

Comment: One more thing. In my opinion you don't need to specify full path in grep. You can simply grep "run_flask" in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the PID of your command immediately after running the `nohup` command and store to a variable.

```
nohup python /home/app/run_flask.py > /home/temp/run_flask.out 2> /home/temp/run_flask.err &
var=$!
```

Or to save to a file

```
nohup python /home/app/run_flask.py > /home/temp/run_flask.out 2> /home/temp/run_flask.err &
echo $! > saved_pid.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't `var=$(echo $! )` be more like `var=$!`?

Comment: @LéaGris Indeed. Changed